# How to use FontAwsome icon inside the Loading in Ionic 4 as before in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a service just to show/hide a loading over the screen.

Wha I need is to use a Fontawsome icon instead of the ionic icon.

I tried:

```js
show(message ? : string) : void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.loader = this.loadingController.create({
    spinner: null,
    message: "<fa-icon icon='spinner' pulse='true' ></fa-icon>",
    translucent: true,
    showBackdrop: true,
    animated: true,
    keyboardClose: true
  });

  this.loader.then((a: any) => {
    a.present().then(() => {
      if (!this.isLoading) {
        a.dismiss().then(() => console.log('aborting...'));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Result: 
[image]

What can I do?